# About the webdatagrid page setting

Tags: asp.net, webdatagrid

I want to set the datasource of each page separately for WDG.For example,the WDG has three pages and the record count of each page is different.Could it to be done?

Comment: Have you tried something so far? did you get an error? please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to help contributors understand your needs and help you

Comment: So you basically have three separate datagrids? Why not code it as such?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of you who replyed me.I've get it done by adding or deleting datarows in the datasouce of WDG when the pageindex is changing,so the record count of other pages could fit the current page when displaying.